# Magit on Windows: "searching for program: permission denied, git"

Tags: git, magit, microsoft-windows

I installed Magit on Windows, but every time I use it, it give me the error:

```
searching for program: permission denied, git
```

even though I already installed the git software on windows. (it seems that there is no git available from the cmd). I am using the GUI emacs and not emacs from cygwin.

Comment: Change your title to something more specific, like "permission denied with Magit on Windows"

Comment: Did you change `magit-git-executable`?  Does it help to set this variable to the *absolute* path to your Git executable?

Comment: @lunaryorn No I didn't change that. There is no such variable.

Comment: @Husain What is your Magit version then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run: `M-x eval-expression (executable-find "git")` if it is not found then you need to add git to the `exec-path` list.

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/path/to/folder/containing/git/executable")
```

Look at the definition for `magit-git-executable` and you'll see how, if emacs cannot find `git` using `executable-find`, it won't be set correctly.

Comment: I did so. I got nil. So I added "Eval: (add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe")" and that didn't help either.

Comment: @Husain You need to add the **directory containing** the Git executable to `exec-path`, **not** the Git executable itself.  For `magit-git-executable`, you'd need to use the path to the executable, though.

Comment: This also helps for "Searching for program: no such file or directory, git" problem.